# unresolved external symbol even though i think i am linking correctly (MSVC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, sdl, dynamic-linking

i have a project that is using SDL as an external library. The project uses functions such as _SDL_WM_SetCaption, _SDL_FillRect or _SDL_MapRGBA. I have told the linker to include the two libraries SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib and have told it to look in the folder where these libraries are placed. I have also inspected the library files with dumpbin.exe and the functions are there. however, it still doesnt work compiling/linking? why? anyone have any ideas?

edit: here is an example output of the linker/compiler error:

```
14>libtestd.lib(sdlgl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_WM_SetCaption referenced in function "public: void __thiscall SDLGLEngine::SetTitle(char *)" (?SetTitle@SDLGLEngine@@QAEXPAD@Z)
14>libtestd.lib(sdlgl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_FillRect referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SDLGLEngine::Init(int,int,int,bool)" (?Init@SDLGLEngine@@QAE_NHHH_N@Z)
14>libtestd.lib(sdlgl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_MapRGBA referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SDLGLEngine::Init(int,int,int,bool)" (?Init@SDLGLEngine@@QAE_NHHH_N@Z)
14>libtestd.lib(sdlgl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_SetVideoMode referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SDLGLEngine::Init(int,int,int,bool)" (?Init@SDLGLEngine@@QAE_NHHH_N@Z)
14>libtestd.lib(sdlgl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GL_SetAttribute referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SDLGLEngine::Init(int,int,int,bool)" (?Init@SDLGLEngine@@QAE_NHHH_N@Z)
14>libtestd.lib(sdlgl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SDLGLEngine::Init(int,int,int,bool)" (?Init@SDLGLEngine@@QAE_NHHH_N@Z)
14>libtestd.lib(sdlgl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SDLGLEngine::Init(int,int,int,bool)" (?Init@SDLGLEngine@@QAE_NHHH_N@Z)
```

Comment: Do they have the same compile flags? like -MT/-MD? Do you link to debug or release version?

Comment: do you call methods from your code as `_SDL_Init` or `SDL_Init`?

Comment: hmm, i have to check about the SDL_Init...

Comment: Although you wrote `_SDL_FillRect` etc, I guess that you don't have leading underscore in your code, as the compiler will complain instead of linker. Are you really sure your linker settings are correct? can you show them?

Comment: the compile flags seem to be the same, and, as far as i can tell, SDL_Init etc. is called as it is intended to be. I have linked against precompiled version of SDL, so I'm not sure about debug/release. The only guess i can have is that something is not correct there, so, for now, ill try building SDL myself and see what happens. Ill post back when thats done.

Comment: please also check if you are mixing 32 and 64 bit builds.

Comment: ye, i think that is the problem, i was linking to SDL x64 libraries. ill try now

Comment: ye, it worked (obviously). thanks for the help!! :) Can I accept ur comment as answer? Thanks also to gongzhitaao for the help!! :)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Do you have time to copy that comment to an answer?  :)

Comment: Sure, i also added other possibilities if someone has same symptoms for different reason

Comment: To anyone else who comes across this problem, don't choose x64 or x86 builds based on your operating system type, rather based on the version of you Microsoft Visual Studio. If it's in Program Files (x86) then use the x86 one.

Answer (score 9):

Possible reasons:

- the sdl.lib and sdlmain.lib settings are not added to dependency list
- their location was not added to the list of directories where the linker looks
- you have mismatched 32 and 64 bit versions of the libraries.